Power BI Service: Unable to refresh dataset with dynamic sources from CKAN
I’m using Power Query (M) in Power BI to retrieve data from the CKAN API. The script starts by calling the package_show endpoint to get a list of resources, then filters the resources and loads each CSV using Web.Contents([url]), where [url] comes from a column in the table. While this works perfectly in Power BI Desktop, it fails to refresh in Power BI Service with the error:

This dataset includes a dynamic data source. Since dynamic data sources aren't refreshed in the Power BI service, this dataset won't be refreshed.

I understand that Power BI treats URLs derived from table data as dynamic sources. How can I restructure my query or parameters to enable scheduled refresh in Power BI Service without knowing all the URLs in advance, while still leveraging the information returned by package_show?
let
  // Base parameters
  BaseUrl = "https://donnees.montreal.ca",
  Endpoint = "/api/3/action/package_show",
  PackageId = "postes-electifs",

  // Initial request to retrieve package information
  Source = Json.Document(
    Web.Contents(BaseUrl, [RelativePath=Endpoint, Query=[id=PackageId]])
  ),

  // Extract the list of resources from the result.resources field
  Resources = Source[result][resources],

  // Convert the list of resources into a table
  ResourcesTable = Table.FromList(Resources, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),

  // Expand the columns of each resource (id, name, format, url, etc.)
  ExpandedResources = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(
    ResourcesTable, 
    "Column1", 
    {"id", "name", "format", "url"}, 
    {"id", "name", "format", "url"}
  ),

  // Add a "CSV" column that loads each CSV file from the "url" column
  CSVData = Table.AddColumn(
    ExpandedResources, 
    "CSV", 
    each Csv.Document(
        Web.Contents([url]), 
        [Delimiter=",", Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]
    )
  ),

  // Promote headers for each table
  CSVWithHeaders = Table.TransformColumns(
    CSVData, 
    {"CSV", each Table.PromoteHeaders(_)}
  ),

  // Combine all CSV tables into a single final table
  AllData = Table.Combine(CSVWithHeaders[CSV])

in
  AllData


To resolve this, I avoided directly using [url] from a table (which was populated by the package_show endpoint). Instead, I leveraged the datastore_search API with pagination to fetch the data for each resource. By passing the resource_id explicitly in the RelativePath and Query options of Web.Contents, I ensured the data source is considered static by Power BI.
Original Code (Dynamic URL from Table):
Web.Contents([url], [Delimiter=",", Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])

Updated Code (Using API with Pagination):
Web.Contents(
"https://donnees.montreal.ca",
[
    RelativePath = "/api/3/action/datastore_search",
    Query = [
        resource_id = ResourceId,
        limit = "1000",
        offset = Text.From(OffsetValue)
    ]
]

)
This approach avoids using [url] from the table and instead retrieves data directly from the API in a predictable and static manner, allowing the dataset to refresh successfully in Power BI Service.
